# Running container fails with failed to add the host cannot allocate memory

Tags: docker, out-of-memory, docker-ce, docker-cli

OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.7 (Ootpa)
Version:

```
$ sudo yum list installed | grep docker
containerd.io.x86_64                         1.6.9-3.1.el8                               @docker-ce-stable
docker-ce.x86_64                             3:20.10.21-3.el8                            @docker-ce-stable
docker-ce-cli.x86_64                         1:20.10.21-3.el8                            @docker-ce-stable
docker-ce-rootless-extras.x86_64             20.10.21-3.el8                              @docker-ce-stable
docker-scan-plugin.x86_64                    0.21.0-3.el8                                @docker-ce-stable
```

Out of hundreds os docker calls made over days, a few of them fails. This is the schema of the commandline:

```
/usr/bin/docker
run
-u
1771:1771
-a
stdout
-a
stderr
-v
/my_path:/data
--rm
my_image:latest
my_entry
--my_args
```

The failure:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint recursing_aryabhata on network bridge: failed to add the host (veth6ad97f8) <=> sandbox (veth23b66ce) pair interfaces: cannot allocate memory.
```

It is not reproducible. The failure rate is less than one percent. At the time this error happens system has lots of free memory. Around the time that this failure happens, the application is making around 5 docker calls per second. Each call take about 5 to 10 seconds to complete.

#### Update Oct 19th 2023

Good ongoing discussion here: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1443